# Merging Linux Changes into Android Kernel Project

Tags: android, linux, git, merge, kernel

Trying to figure this out here. Trying to merge the latest linux 3.0 changes (3.0.41) to a kernel project I'm working on based off HTC source (3.0.8). I downloaded the source, committed the base files, added the linux-stable tree as a remote, and tried to merge it with 'git merge linux-stable/linux-3.0.y'. In the response, I am given:

error: Untracked working tree file 'Documentation/DocBook/dvb/dvbstb.pdf' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting

Which is a file in .gitignore. If I git add -f that file, it just errors with the next file in the .gitignore. Is there a way for me go merge this cleanly without these errors? I don't want to do it commit by commit, since there would be thousands of commits to merge.

Comment: After you added files to `.gitignore`, did you run `git rm --cached`?

Comment: The source actuallly came with a .gitignore. git rm --cached does nothing but bring up some flags. Do you mean git rm . --cached?

Comment: The files themselves. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4858141/877115

Comment: @Christopher For some reason, every directory in the source has a .gitignore. Not just one. There are 30+ .gitignore files. There must be an easier way. If I remove all of the .gitignore files, I get merge conflicts.

Comment: Is your project a public repo? It'd be useful to see it if it is.

Comment: @Christopher https://github.com/dmeadows013/fireball-kernel just stock so far.

Comment: Got it. One other question: Is the branch you're trying to merge public? Would like to test a theory out (as well as some possible resolutions) locally. You just grabbing a branch off the kernel source? Which repo?

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you can find the HTC source as an existing git repository, you will be **much** better off.  The lack of proper git history in your manually constructed tree is inevitably going to cause conflicts.  The HTC source is effectively a branch off vanilla Android, which is (presumably) a branch off vanilla Linux, but without the full history, git can attempt nothing better than an effective two-way merge, since it doesn't have the common ancestor in order to do a proper three-way merge.  So unless you are an experienced kernel programmer who can handle these conflicts, I expect you will have great difficulty.

Anyway, if obtaining the full history is not possible, your trees will not have a common root, so you will need to consult [How do I join two git repos without a common root, where all modified files are the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404628/how-do-i-join-two-git-repos-without-a-common-root-where-all-modified-files-are).

Regarding the `.gitignore` issue, if you have files which are ignored in the 3.0.8 tree but tracked in the 3.0.41 three then it sounds like you have a mismatch between the `.gitignore` files in each tree, so you should compare them, try to figure out why, and decide what should be tracked and what shouldn't.  `git blame .gitignore` in the 3.0.41 tree might help with this.  The 3.0.41 tree will be the more authoritative of the two repositories, since it has complete history and will be internally self-consistent, so you could try transplanting its `.gitignore` into the 3.0.8 tree before your initial import commit.  Also be aware that there could be `.gitignore` files anywhere in the tree, not just at the top-level (I don't know off-hand if the Linux kernel does this).